# What is RUST_BACKTRACE supposed to tell me?

Tags: debugging, rust, backtrace, panic

My program is panicking so I followed its advice to run `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` and I get this (just a little snippet).

```
1: 0x800c05b5 - std::sys::imp::backtrace::tracing::imp::write::hf33ae72d0baa11ed
            at /buildslave/rust-buildbot/slave/stable-dist-rustc-linux/build/src/libstd/sys/unix/backtrace/tracing/gcc_s.rs:42

2: 0x800c22ed - std::panicking::default_hook::{{closure}}::h59672b733cc6a455
            at /buildslave/rust-buildbot/slave/stable-dist-rustc-linux/build/src/libstd/panicking.rs:351
```

If the program panics it stops the whole program, so where can I figure out at which line it's panicking on?

Is this line telling me there is a problem at line 42 and line 351?

The whole backtrace is on this image, I felt it would be to messy to copy and paste it here.

[image]

I've never heard of a stack trace or a back trace. I'm compiling with warnings, but I don't know what debugging symbols are.

Comment: Well, i figured it out. it was on line 334 gg. Anyways, you should post an answer and i'll give you the best answer if you want.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

#### What is a stack trace?

If your program panics, you encountered a bug and would like to fix it; a stack trace wants to help you here. When the panic happens, you would like to know the cause of the panic (the function in which the panic was triggered). But the function directly triggering the panic is usually not enough to really see what's going on. Therefore we also print the function that called the previous function... and so on. We trace back all function calls leading to the panic up to `main()` which is (pretty much) the first function being called.

#### What are debug symbols?

When the compiler generates the machine code, it pretty much only needs to emit instructions for the CPU. The problem is that it's virtually impossible to quickly see from which Rust-function a set of instructions came. Therefore the compiler can insert additional information into the executable that is ignored by the CPU, but is used by debugging tools.

One important part are file locations: the compiler annotates which instruction came from which file at which line. This also means that we can later see where a specific function is defined. If we don't have debug symbols, we can't.

In your stack trace you can see a few file locations:

```
1: 0x800c05b5 - std::sys::imp::backtrace::tracing::imp::write::hf33ae72d0baa11ed
        at /buildslave/rust-buildbot/slave/stable-dist-rustc-linux/build/src/libstd/sys/unix/backtrace/tracing/gcc_s.rs:42
```

The Rust standard library is shipped with debug symbols. As such, we can see where the function is defined (`gcc_s.rs` line 42).

If you compile in debug mode (`rustc` or `cargo build`), debug symbols are activated by default. If you, however, compile in release mode (`rustc -O` or `cargo build --release`), debug symbols are disabled by default as they increase the executable size and... usually aren't important for the end user. You can tweak whether or not you want debug symbols in your `Cargo.toml` in a specific [`profile` section](http://doc.crates.io/manifest.html#the-profile-sections) with the `debug` key.

#### What are all these strange functions?!

When you first look at a stack trace you might be confused by all the strange function names you're seeing. Don't worry, this is normal! You are interested in what part of *your* code triggered the panic, but the stack trace shows all functions somehow involved. In your example, you can ignore the first 9 entries: those are just functions handling the panic and generating the exact message you are seeing.

Entry 10 is still not your code, but might be interesting as well: the panic was triggered in the `index()` function of `Vec<T>` which is called when you use the `[]` operator. And finally, entry 11 shows a function *you* defined. But you might have noticed that this entry is missing a file location... the above section describes how to fix that.

---

### What do to with a stack trace? (tl;dr)

1. **Activate debug symbols** if you haven't already (e.g. just compile in debug mode).
2. **Ignore any functions from `std` and `core`** at the top of the stack trace.
3. Look at **the first function you defined**, find the corresponding location in your file and fix the bug.
4. If you haven't already, change all `camelCase` function and method names to `snake_case` to stick to the community wide style guide.

Comment: Rust backtraces [are getting better](https://users.rust-lang.org/t/improvement-of-rust-backtrace-merged-on-latest-nightlies/9735).

Comment: @PavelStrakhov Sweet :3 the current back traces are rather... ugly. I will update my answer once this hits stable, which should be in 2 weeks (I think).